# Center of an abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Prove if $G$ is non abelian group, then exists an abelian subgroup $H$ which contains $Z(G)$ and $H≠Z(G)$.

Comment: Hint: what is the group generated by $Z(G)$?

Comment: Z(G) is the center of G

Comment: I know. Have you thought about the hint?

Comment: The group generated by $\;Z(G)\;$ is...$\;Z(G)\;$ , of course.

Comment: @Timbuc quite right, I meant add a new point to it and generate the subgroup. Bit sloppy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose $x\in G-Z(G)$. Then we may take $H$ to be the subgroup generated by $x$ and $Z(G)$. $H$ clearly properly contains the center. To see that it is abelian, note that $x$ commutes with every power of itself as well as every element of $Z(G)$. Elements of $H$ are therefore of the form $x^ky$ for integers $k$ and $y\in Z(G)$, and these elements all commute with each other.